# Selecting from multiple tables and adding up all occurrences from 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

I have two tables, one with an accountID, hours, and date columns and the other with accountID, minutes, and date columns. The first table will only ever have 1 entry for each date but the second could have multiple. What I want to do is select everything from both tables where the accountID's match up, but add up the minutes of each occurrence in the second table.

I apologize if this makes no sense. Here's an example:

Table1:

```
Account ID | hours | date
1             4       2014-1-1
1             3       2014-1-2
2             2       2014-1-3
3             3       2014-1-3
```

Table2:

```
Account ID | minutes | date
1            34        2014-1-1
1            36        2014-1-1
1            32        2014-1-2
1            12        2014-1-2
```

I don't want more than 1 row per day so the minutes for Jan 1 and Jan 2 need to be combined, is this possible?

EDIT: I want the hours from table 1 and the summation of the minutes by date from table 2. So on Jan 1 minutes would be 70 and hours would be 4.

Comment: Don't apologize. Make it make sense.

Comment: I don't know how to word it which is why I gave an example. Does that not make sense either?

Comment: I think the example is incomplete. Can you think why I might think that?

Comment: The confusion is in what your expected output should be. You want to sum minutes over the second table, but you don't really give a reason why you need the first table.

Comment: I need the hours from the first table

Comment: But if you combine the minutes across all dates from the second table, do you also want to combine hours across all dates? It would help to put the expected output table into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a group by clause on a table join. In this case you'll need a double group by since you want id, date pairings. You'll have to sum the hours even though you indicated they are unique to account ids to prevent the grouping clause from complaining.

```
SELECT `Account ID`, `date`, SUM(`hours`) AS `hours`, SUM(`minutes`) AS `minutes`
FROM `table1` 
JOIN `table2` ON (`table1`.`Account ID` = `table2`.`Account ID` AND `table1`.`date` = `table2`.`date`)
GROUP BY `Account ID`, `date`;
```

Comment: Yes, the `join` clause will combine the tables where the `on` condition is met.

Comment: When using mysql_fetch_array on the results it is erring because it is a boolean, why might this be?

Comment: From the docs mysql_fetch_array returns "FALSE if there are no more rows". You probably have a variable misnamed/typoed. You should probably try this query in the mysql console and play with it until it returns results that look correct. I used variables names based on your question, which are probably different than your database table names.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand about Table1, but summing minutes from Table2 to have distinct AccountIDs is simple. Try it with function sum and grouping like this:

```
select AccountID, sum(minutes) as mins
from Table2
group by AccoutID
```

This will give you this:

AccountID | mins

1         | 114

I hope this helps. :)

---

Ok, if I understood well your comments, you want this (without information about AccountID):

```
select sum(hours) as H, sum(minutes) as M, date
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.date=Table2.date
group by date
```

Comment: I want to sum it up by date

Comment: To sum what by date, the first table?
Google the references and examples for sum and group by.

Comment: Minutes from the second table. I want Total minutes and hours from each date. So Jan 1 would be 4 from hours and 70 from minutes (36+34)

Comment: I've edited previous answer. If you need the AccountID information also, take a look at @Pyrce's answer. Good luck! :)